# rtrim() is trimming the string even when charlist doesn't match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to rtrim() the complete datetime whenever the time is 00:00:00.
In this scenario, I just want to display date without any time.

Code:

```
echo rtrim('26-10-2015 06:00:00',' 00:00:00');
```

Result:

```
26-10-2015 06
```

I want to match the complete string to apply the right trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you obtain is correct. The *character_mask* parameter help says:

> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the `character_mask` parameter. *Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With `..` you can specify a range of characters.*

So, you strip the `0`, `:` and a space from the string end.

If you still want to use your approach, use

```
echo rtrim(rtrim('26-10-2015 06:00:00','0..9:'));
```

The `0..9` "matches" all digits and the outer `rtrim()` will get rid of any trailing whitespace that remains after the custom `rtrim`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/jrO3er)

If you plan to change the approach, you may use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to obtain the substring before the first space like this:

```
echo strstr('26-10-2015 06:00:00',' ', true);
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/RIGf1q)

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev for explaining in detail. Basically, this approach was used in a legacy code, I am working on right now. I think that its better to change this approach.

Comment: What approach do you want to switch to? Getting the substring before the first space, right :) ? Use `strstr`. I think it will be much more efficient *unless* you need to obtain specific DateTime details.

Comment: but I also need to write an extra if() to check the time for 00:00:00 scenario

Comment: Please post your potential input and requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use `date()` and `strtotime()`

```
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime('26-10-2015 06:00:00'));
```